# Magento 2 Product Detail Page Not Loading/Showing

Tags: magento2.3

After upgrading to Magento 2.3.2, the product detail page is not loading or showing anymore. It gives error `This page isn’t working. www.mywebsite.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500`

When I checked the log I see `Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor does not exist {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor does not exist at /home/.../public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:19)"} []`

I have ran the commands, updated, granted permission, deployed static content, compiled, reindexed, flushed cache... Etc, but still the problem is not solved.

Product Detail Page Error Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/pgj0v9

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you removed var/generated folder manually?

Comment: Yes. I did with the following command 'sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/ pub/static/_requirejs pub/static/deployed_version.txt var/cache var/page_cache var/generation var/view_preprocessed var/session generated/code'

Comment: @aravind Thanks for the help. When I checked var/ folder there is no "generated" folder or directory in there. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need change the file/folder ownership.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .
```

Please make sure what web server are you using. Apache: www-data:www-data, nginx: nginx:nginx

Comment: Server: Apache/2.4.41

Comment: Still not working.